# Ubuntu installer freezes at language selection with Aero 15x v8

Tags: system-installation, nvidia-geforce

I am trying to install Ubuntu 18 as a dual boot, via USB, which was created using Rufus as per the instructions on the tutorials.ubuntu site.

The computer freezes up at the Language selection screen and does not go any further. Cannot do anything, have to long press the power button for hard restart.

What can I do to get past this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question.

I had to put in the boot settings `nouveau.modeset=0` after `splash quiet` to disable the nouveau nvidia graphics driver.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on my 15x v8 and I THINK that unplugging my 9-in-1 USB-C hub (connected to display, mouse and keyboard) was what allowed me to get through the install.

FWIW, you'll probably want to disable 3D Graphics Acceleration (the dGPU) in BIOS if it freezes up at login.  Getting the dGPU working again... well that might require posting another question.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Bro I had through this situation but it is solved now

Actually if you plug your HDMI port connect to any monitor resolution 1920x1080 it won't freeze but it will freeze when it's not connected to HDMI.

To solve the problem, after the installation, you can go to settings and install additional drivers, select the other NVIDIA driver from the thing that is selected by default.

After that it's no longer necessary to plug in HDMI just to boot your PC.

I am using Ubuntu Mate 16.04 and dual booting from the same PC you are using, AERO 15x V8.